# c++ Linking Error with const member function in a class

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a declaration something like

```
    class ABC_EXPORT abc
    {
    ....

public:
     xyz foo1(const arg1 a, const arg3 b) const; //defined in cpp file
     xyz foo2(const arg1 a, const arg2 b) const { return foo1(a, convert_to_arg3(b));}
    };
```

This gets built into a DLL library, and another project calls `foo2`. I get linker error LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol. However If I remove `const` from the definition of `foo2` linking is resolved. Could someone explain me whats going on here? I am on VS2012 on windows 7

Comment: Have you tried moving the definitions to the header file and attempting it again? I think libraries which are not header only require special treatment

Comment: Surely you are linking a stale version of the import library, one that was created before you added const.  Do make sure the project still builds correctly, double-check the timestamp on the .lib file, always avoid copying files by hand.

Comment: You could also check the symbols in the library, unmangle the names, and make sure that it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: @HansPassant I did do a clean build

Comment: Please post the full linker error message and the header file used by the caller of the DLL.  Something to do with method signatures, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the function signatures of the declaration and the definition match. One common mistake is to forget the `const` specifier on the function definition. For example,

```
struct A
{
    void do_foo_const(int a, int b) const;
};

// An incorrect definition.
// Notice the missing 'const' here V
void A::do_foo_const(int a, int b)
{
    ...
}


// correct definition.
void A::do_foo_const(int a, int b) const
{
    ...
}
```

This separation allows the const- and non-const- versions of the functions to exist beside eachother, and return different results. An example in the C++ standard library that uses this feature is [`std::vector<T>::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at). Notice how the const version returns a const reference, but the non-const version returns a non-const reference.

Comment: If you leave the const qualifier off the function definition then it won't compile.  Anyway, the function in question is entirely defined in the header file.  Something else is going on here, see my comment above.